# How to add nav icon images using max-width property in CSS

Tags: html, css, nav

So I'm working on a personal project and I'd like to add icon images to the left of each nav menu item. 3 things are bugging me;

1. I can't get the icons to sit left of the menu items
2. I can't get the icons to resize using the max-width property
3. I also need the icons to remain in place on hovering.

http://www.toastcafebar.com/nav/

```
<nav role="navigation">
  <ul>
  <a class="cinema" href="cinema.html">Movies</a>
  <a class="tv" href="tv.html">T.V Shows</a>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

...and the CSS

```
nav[role="navigation"] ul {
display: inline-block;
text-align: center;
margin-top: 50px;
} 

nav[role="navigation"] ul a {
width: auto;
margin: 0 50px;
font-size: 2em;
padding: .5em;
width: auto;
}

a.cinema {
display: block;
background: url(images/pop.png) no-repeat left center;
padding-left: 75px;
}

.tv {
display: block;
background: url(images/tv.png) no-repeat;
padding-left: 100px;
}


nav a:link, a:visited {
font-weight: normal;
text-decoration: none;
outline: none;
color: #000;
}

nav a:hover {
color: #999;
background: #666;
-moz-border-radius: .5em;
border-radius: .55em;
padding: .25em;
}
```

Any suggestions?

Cheers in advance

Comment: `max-width` is not CSS3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your markup is a bit funky. If you have a `<ul>` element, you should only have `<li>` children.

HTML:

```
<nav role="navigation">
    <ul>
        <li><a class="cinema" href="cinema.html">Movies</a></li>
        <li><a class="tv" href="tv.html">T.V Shows</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
nav[role="navigation"] ul {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 50px; } 
nav[role="navigation"] ul li { 
    font-size: 2em;
    margin: 0 50px;
    display: inline-block; }
nav[role="navigation"] ul a {
    background-position: .5em 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    text-decoration: none;
    outline: none;
    color: #000;
    padding: .5em .5em .5em 75px;
    display: block; }
nav[role="navigation"] ul li a.cinema { background-image: url(http://www.toastcafebar.com/nav/images/pop.png); }
nav[role="navigation"] ul li a.tv { background-image: url(http://www.toastcafebar.com/nav/images/tv.png); }
nav[role="navigation"] ul li a:hover {
    color: #999;
    background-color: #666;
    -moz-border-radius: .5em;
    border-radius: .55em; }
```

Preview: http://jsfiddle.net/Wexcode/bGNgr/

Comment: Awesome. Thanks @wex. Apologies for the funky markup...I got a little muddled between different version!

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is the `<a>` tags to `display:block;`, and have the icon as a background image, aligned left with no-repeat. Then make sure you apply padding-left on the `<a>`so the text doesn't overlap the image. For example:

```
a.cinema {
    display: block;
    background: url(/path/to/img.png) no-repeat left center;
    padding-left: 90px;
}
```

Use that as a base! No need for max-width...

Comment: I tried the above and I get the following http://www.toastcafebar.com/nav/ padding-left doesn't seem to do anything. I also need to have the menu display inline. Would display:inline-block achieve anything?

Comment: I don't think you're adding the padding? It worked for me when I added it in firebug. Also, your `<a>` tags should be inside `<li>` tags.

Answer (score 1):

To get the icon to autoresize to fit the "button size" you could use the CSS3 property "background-size". But I think the best way is to resize the icons manually, some browsers does not support CSS3 properties correct yet.

http://www.css3.info/preview/background-size/

Answer (score 1):

Use both classes as follows, you may reach to answer,

```
nav a:hover {
    -moz-border-radius: 0.5em 0.5em 0.5em 0.5em;
    background: url(images/pop.png) no-repeat scroll left center #666666;
    color: #999999;
}

a.cinema {
    display: block;
    background: url(/path/to/img.png) no-repeat left center;
    text-indent: 35px;
}
```

Comment: @Jedda I observed in the hover, you have only used background color, then it automatically set background image to none.